# Is it possible to randomly hash classes with build process?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

I'm doing something like this in the development environment.

```
import "./main.css"

    const App = () =>  <div className="foo-bar-baz"> <h1>Hello react</h1> </div>
```

Now I built this, and I get an output like below.

```
<div class="foo-bar-baz"> <h1>Hello react</h1> </div>
```

But that's not what I wanted. I want class names to be hashed. Lıke this

```
<div class="fx09_jnm_1 _Y1gn2f"> <h1>Hello react</h1> </div>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry but didn't get that? can you explain exactly what you want? if your className changed to hashed, you should change CSS also!

Comment: what do you exactly wants, I understand that your classname would be hashed. so kindly look in to it will help for your problem or not https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#localidentname

Comment: to get hashed classname, you'll need to configure css-modules with webpack.

this should help

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-css-modules

then like @RaghulSK said you can use  https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#localidentname  to configure how you want your classes to be hashed

Comment: Yes. I think this will work for me

Comment: @heisanbug, Actually, how can I do this https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#localidentname with the CRA? "npm run eject" without running

Comment: @matt cra has already support for css modules. you can read more about it here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Comment: @heisanbug Yes, but it does hash in the following format

[filename][classname]_[base64:hash]

Comment: @heisanbug So I mean, it's okay when I do this myself with the normal webpack configuration. But CRA does not hash file and class names, it just adds a hash value next to it. How can I remove it?
https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#alternate-bind-version-for-css-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed. But after running "npm run eject" I made the following configurations in config / webpack.config.js file

Now there is another problem. Isn't there a way to do this without running "npm run eject"?

```
{
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
                localIdentName:'__[hash:base64:5]',
              }),
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            {
              test: /\.css$/,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'style-loader'
                },
                {
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                  options: {
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    modules: {
                      localIdentName: '[hash:base64:5]__[hash:base64:5]___[hash:base64:5]'
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
```

```
npm run eject
npm i classnames --save
```

in your component

```
import styles from 'main.module.css'
import classnames from 'classnames/bind'


const cx = classnames.bind(styles) 


return (
 
<div className={ cx('foobar') } > .... </div>
)
```